# USB audio For Android Platform

Tags: android, audio, usb, alsa

I am using Android 4.2.2 on Qualcomm APQ8064 Chip set. I want to enable audio output to the USB headset. I tried using aplay command but no luck. The driver for usb-audio is already there in the code. Everything is integrated but i don't get any output on the usb-headset. Any flags that need to be set?? Any lead will be of great help.

@Micheal:Following are the logs for the same, I just noticed that below logs from AudioUsbALSA can also be seen when the USB headset is not connected.

```
3502:I/InputReader(  676): Device added: id=8, name='Logitech Inc. Logitech USB Headset H340', sources=0x00000501
3504:D/StatusBar.NetworkController(  769): refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
3505:D/StatusBar.NetworkController(  769): refreshViews connected={ } level=?? combinedSignalIconId=0x7f02013d/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_null combinedActivityIconId=0x0 mobileLabel=No Internet connection wifiLabel= emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel=No Internet connection mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f02013d mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020073 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mDataSignalIconId=0x7f02013d mDataTypeIconId=0x0 mQSDataTypeIconId=0x0 mNoSimIconId=0x0 mWifiIconId=0x0 mQSWifiIconId=0x0 mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x1080563
3600:V/PhoneStatusBar(  769): setLightsOn(true)
3627:V/AudioHardwareALSA(  272): closeUsbPlaybackIfNothingActive, musbPlaybackState: 0
3628:D/AudioUsbALSA(  272): exitPlaybackThread, mproxypfdPlayback: -1
3629:D/AudioUsbALSA(  272): closeDevice handle 0x0
3630:D/AudioUsbALSA(  272): closeDevice handle 0x0
3710:V/PhoneStatusBar(  769): setLightsOn(true)
3730:V/AudioHardwareALSA(  272): closeUsbPlaybackIfNothingActive, musbPlaybackState: 0
3731:D/AudioUsbALSA(  272): exitPlaybackThread, mproxypfdPlayback: -1
3732:D/AudioUsbALSA(  272): closeDevice handle 0x0
3733:D/AudioUsbALSA(  272): closeDevice handle 0x0
```

Comment: Which code base are you building from? Something from the CodeAurora Forums? Qualcomm uses `DEVICE_OUT_ANLG_DOCK_HEADSET` for device-mode USB headsets IIRC. Have you checked if you get a `setDeviceConnectionState` for that device in `AudioPolicyManagerALSA` ?

Comment: Is `QCOM_USBAUDIO_ENABLED` set when you build the audio.primary module (i.e. does the code in `AudioUsbALSA` ever run)? Have you tried manipulating the volume for the USB ALSA card? (sometimes the default volume is really low; I've run into this myself).

Comment: @Micheal:
I am using code from CodeAurora Forums. Yes when I plug in the USB Headset I get the following logs :

E/AudioPolicyManagerALSA(287):setDeviceConnectionState() device: 800,state 1,address 
E/AudioPolicyManagerALSA(287):setDeviceConnectionState() connecting device 800
W/AudioPolicyManagerALSA(287):checkOutputsForDevice() could not open output for device 800

Comment: W/AudioPolicyManagerALSA(287):checkOutputsForDevice() could not open output for device 800
W/AudioPolicyManagerALSA(287):checkOutputsForDevice() could not open output for device 800
E/AudioPolicyManagerALSA(287):setDeviceConnectionState() checkOutputsForDevice() returned 2 outputs

Comment: Is `AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_ANLG_DOCK_HEADSET` enabled for any output in your `audio_policy.conf` file?

Comment: @Micheal:
Will try putting some logs in AudioUsbALSA and check if the file is actually executed during run-time or not.
Yes QCOM_USBAUDIO_ENABLED and AudioUsbALSA are included in the .mk file.
How do I manipulate the volume for USB ALSA card.
Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: You should be able to list the available ALSA controls and write to them using the `alsa_mixer` utility (you may have to build alsa_mixer yourself). I don't remember the exact syntax off the top of my head since it's been a while since I worked with this stuff.

Comment: @Micheal:Yes AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_ANLG_DOCK_HEADSET as well as AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_ALL_USB is there in audio_policy.conf.

Comment: @Michael:I just checked the usb mixer settings and following is the observation:


/proc/asound/card0/usbmixer

USB Mixer: usb_id=0x046d0a38, ctrlif=0, ctlerr=0
Card: Logitech Inc. Logitech USB Headset H340 at usb-msm_ehci_host.1-1.1, full speed

Unit: 5
    Control: name="PCM Playback Volume", index=0
    Info: id=5, control=2, cmask=0x3, channels=2, type="S16"
    Volume: min=-10496, max=768, dBmin=-4100, dBmax=300
Unit: 5
    Control: name="PCM Playback Switch", index=0
    Info: id=5, control=1, cmask=0x0, channels=1, type="INV_BOOLEAN"
    Volume: min=0, max=1, dBmin=0, dBmax=0

Comment: I am using the following command:

'aplay -D hw:0,0 -V -C1 -R44100 -FS16_LE /data/test_mono_44100Hz_16bit_PCM.wav'

Result:
Aplay:aplay: cannot open '/data/test_mono_44100Hz_16bit'

'cat /proc/asound/card0/stream0
Logitech Inc. Logitech USB Headset H340 at usb-msm_ehci_host.1-1.1, full speed : USB Audio

Playback:
  Status: Stop
  Interface 1
    Altset 1
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ASYNC)
    Rates: 44100

Capture:
  Status: Stop
  Interface 2
    Altset 1
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 IN (ASYNC)
    Rates: 44100'

Comment: `aplay` apparently can't find the audio file: _"aplay: cannot open '/data/test_mono_44100Hz_16bit' "_

Comment: @Michael:Yes that's what is bugging me, the file is very much present and I have played it through UI and it plays fine on the HDMI.

Comment: Apparently Qualcomm's `aplay` has a 30-character limit for the filename(!) (see https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/hardware/qcom/audio/tree/libalsa-intf/aplay.c?h=jb_mr1#n918). So you'll have to use a shorter name.

Comment: @Michael: I was successful in playing a wave file using the following command:
"'aplay -D hw:1,0 -V -C2 -R44100 -FS16_LE /data/t_st_44100Hz_16bit_.wav'"

But what I understand, by using aplay command I am bypassing stagefright(android) and directly playing from ALSA, now i want to implement usb output in my code so that instead of output coming from speaker it comes through the USB HeadSet.
I am trying to explore on this, but any help from your end would be really great.

Comment: The first step would probably be to add some logs in `AudioUsbALSA`, `AudioHardwareALSA` and `AlsaDevice` to make sure that the USB playback code is running, that the correct ALSA UCM file has been loaded, etc.

Comment: @Michael:Sorry for such a late reply... I have put logs in the files you specified, I am able to see these files in the logcat as well.