# USB Audio on Android 5.1 Samsung S4 Mini

Tags: android, audio, usb, alsa, tinyalsa

I wanted to test USB Audio on my Samsung S4 Mini GT-I9195 running Android 5.1 (Bliss Pop, which is partly based on Cyanogenmod). I´ve found another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604002/usb-audio-for-android-platform?newreg=623b69544c89461a8dcae92427c333ca) and I too can successfully aplay a wav to hw:1,0, but I´m not able play sounds from any app. For me it seems, that the stream isn´t correctly routed to hw:1,0. Any thought´s?

```
V/WiredAccessoryManager(  612): Headset UEVENT: {SUBSYSTEM=switch, SEQNUM=3196, ACTION=change, SWITCH_STATE=1, SWITCH_NAME=usb_audio, DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/switch/usb_audio}  
I/Choreographer(  808): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.  
V/WiredAccessoryManager(  612): newName=usb_audio newState=4 headsetState=4 prev headsetState=0   
V/WiredAccessoryManager(  612): device usb_audio connected  
I/AudioFlinger(  214): HAL output buffer size 448 frames, normal sink buffer size 896 frames  
I/AudioFlinger(  214): HAL output buffer size 448 frames, normal sink buffer size 448 frames  
I/AudioFlinger(  214): HAL output buffer size 448 frames, normal sink buffer size 896 frames  
I/AudioFlinger(  214): HAL output buffer size 448 frames, normal sink buffer size 448 frames  
D/ALSAStreamOps(  214): setParameters(): keyRouting with device 0x0  
E/ALSAStreamOps(  214): must not change mDevices to 0  
D/UsbHostManager(  612): Added device UsbDevice[mName=/dev/bus/usb/001/002,mVendorId=2235,mProductId=10498,mClass=0,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mManufacturerName=Burr-Brown from TI              ,mProductName=USB Audio CODEC ,mSerialNumber=null,mConfigurations=[  
D/UsbHostManager(  612): UsbConfiguration[mId=1,mName=null,mAttributes=128,mMaxPower=50,mInterfaces=[  
D/EventHub(  612): No input device configuration file found for device 'Burr-Brown from TI               USB Audio CODEC '.  
W/EventHub(  612): Unable to disable kernel key repeat for /dev/input/event11: Function not implemented  
I/EventHub(  612): New device: id=12, fd=253, path='/dev/input/event11', name='Burr-Brown from TI               USB Audio CODEC ', classes=0x80000001, configuration='', keyLayout='/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl', keyCharacterMap='/system/usr/keychars/Generic.kcm', builtinKeyboard=false, wakeMechanism=EVIOCSSUSPENDBLOCK, usingClockIoctl=true  
I/InputReader(  612): Device added: id=12, name='Burr-Brown from TI               USB Audio CODEC ', sources=0x00000101  
I/AudioFlinger(  214): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb5493008 ready to run  
I/AudioFlinger(  214): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb5515008 ready to run  
I/AudioFlinger(  214): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb389f008 ready to run  
I/AudioFlinger(  214): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb3921008 ready to run  
I/HeadsetService( 1011): Headset=false; Bluetooth=false ; USB=true  
I/HeadsetService( 1011): Preferences updated.  
I/HeadsetService( 1011): Headset=false; Bluetooth=false ; USB=true  
W/AudioPolicyManager(  214): checkOutputsForDevice() could not open output for device 4000  
D/AudioHardwareALSA(  214): useCase HiFi  
D/ALSADevice(  214): route: devices 0x800 in mode 0  
D/ALSADevice(  214): No valid input device: 0  
D/alsa_ucm(  214): snd_use_case_set(): uc_mgr 0xb7190228 identifier _disdev value Speaker  
D/alsa_ucm(  214): disdev: device Speaker not enabled, no need to disable  
D/alsa_ucm(  214): snd_use_case_set(): uc_mgr 0xb7190228 identifier _enadev value USB PROXY Rx  
E/alsa_ucm(  214): No valid device USB PROXY Rx found  
D/ALSADevice(  214): switchDevice: mCurTxUCMDevivce None mCurRxDevDevice USB PROXY Rx  
D/alsa_ucm(  214): snd_use_case_set(): uc_mgr 0xb7190228 identifier _verb value HiFi  
E/alsa_ucm(  214): No valid device found: USB PROXY Rx  
D/ALSADevice(  214): close: handle 0xb71da130 h 0x0  
D/ALSADevice(  214): open: handle 0xb71da130, format 0x2  
D/ALSADevice(  214): Device value returned is hw:0,0  
E/alsa_pcm(  214): cannot open device '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p', errno 22  
E/ALSADevice(  214): open: Failed to initialize ALSA device 'hw:0,0'  
E/AudioHardwareALSA(  214): Device open failed  
W/AudioPolicyManager(  214): checkOutputsForDevice() could not open output for device 4000  
W/AudioPolicyManager(  214): checkOutputsForDevice() could not open output for device 4000  
D/AudioHardwareALSA(  214): openInputStream: devices 0x80000000 format 0x1 channels 49168 sampleRate 48000  
D/AudioHardwareALSA(  214): routing everything from proxy  
I/AudioFlinger(  214): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb385e008 ready to run  
D/AudioStreamInALSA(  214): standby  
D/ALSADevice(  214): standby: handle 0xb72001b0 h 0x0  
D/AudioStreamInALSA(  214): Checking for musbRecordingState 0  
D/AudioHardwareALSA(  214): Closing USB Recording Session as no stream is active  
D/AudioUsbALSA(  214): exitRecordingThread  
D/AudioUsbALSA(  214): write to fd  
D/AudioUsbALSA(  214): closeDevice handle 0x0  
D/AudioUsbALSA(  214): closeDevice handle 0x0  
D/AudioStreamInALSA(  214): standby  
D/ALSADevice(  214): standby: handle 0xb72001b0 h 0x0  
D/AudioStreamInALSA(  214): Checking for musbRecordingState 0  
D/AudioHardwareALSA(  214): Closing USB Recording Session as no stream is active  
D/AudioUsbALSA(  214): exitRecordingThread  
D/AudioUsbALSA(  214): write to fd  
D/AudioUsbALSA(  214): closeDevice handle 0x0  
D/AudioUsbALSA(  214): closeDevice handle 0x0  
D/AudioStreamInALSA(  214): close  
D/AudioStreamInALSA(  214): Deregistering REC bit, musbRecordingState:0  
D/AudioStreamInALSA(  214): close  
D/AudioHardwareALSA(  214): Closing USB Recording Session as no stream is active  
D/AudioUsbALSA(  214): exitRecordingThread  
D/AudioUsbALSA(  214): write to fd  
D/AudioUsbALSA(  214): closeDevice handle 0x0  
D/AudioUsbALSA(  214): closeDevice handle 0x0  
D/ALSAStreamOps(  214): close  
D/ALSAStreamOps(  214): close() : Found mHandle 0xb72001b0, proceeding to close  
D/ALSADevice(  214): close: handle 0xb72001b0 h 0x0  
D/ALSAStreamOps(  214): close  
D/ALSAStreamOps(  214): close() : Found mHandle 0xb72001b0, proceeding to close  
D/ALSADevice(  214): close: handle 0xb72001b0 h 0x0
```